# Calculate $\langle x,y,z\mid 2x=2y=2z\rangle$ generated over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I wish to calculate the $$\langle x,y,z\mid 2x=2y=2z\rangle$$ generated over $\mathbb{Z}$, as a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module with the relations $2x=2y=2z$.

I tried to rewrite it as $$\langle x-y,y-z,z\mid 2(x-y)=0, 2(y-z)=0\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2.$$

Is the working correct? Thanks for verification/correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the right approach. What you are really doing is computing the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of the coefficient matrix of the relations. For example in your case the smith normal form of $\begin{pmatrix}2& -2&0\\0&2&-2\end{pmatrix}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}2& 0&0\\0&2&0\end{pmatrix}$, which implies that the group you have is indeed $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. For computing abelian groups given by generators and relations, performing base change results in a similar relations matrix, and by the Smith normal form we can choose the base change such that the resulting matrix is diagonal, from which the group can be computed easily.